# When to use batch normalization in a Fully Convolutional Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, normalization, artificial-intelligence

I understand what batch normalization does but I'm not sure at what point it becomes overkill.

With regards to a [U-net](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf), based on just the rough definition that batch normalization normalizes the output of the previous activation layer, I'd assume that I should have a batch normalization layer after every conv layer. However, this seems like slightly overkill to me. Would it make more sense to just have it before every pooling layer? Or in other words, at the end of every "block?"

In fact, another detail I want to address is, can batch normalization be used after max pooling layers, dropout layers, etc?